# Regular Expression with Connect by

Tags: oracle

I have this query:

```
select regexp_substr('1,2,3,4,5','[^,]+',1,level) 
from test1 
connect by instr('1,2,3,4,5',',',1,level-1)>0;
```

Please help me to understand this query especially the use of a level and connect by and level-1.

Answer (score 0):

LEVEL and CONNECT BY are used to generate sequences, see this simple example:

```
select level
from dual
connect by level < 10;

LEVEL
=======
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

`instr('1,2,3,4,5', ',' , 1, level-1) > 0` counts the number of elements separated by comma maybe this version is easier to understand, it does the same:

```
select regexp_substr('1,2,3,4,5','[^,]+',1,level) 
from dual 
connect by LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT('1,2,3,4,5', ',')+1;
```

`LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT('1,2,3,4,5', ',')+1` or `instr('1,2,3,4,5', ',' , 1, level-1) > 0` means "run five times".

So, your select is basically a shortcut for

```
select regexp_substr('1,2,3,4,5','[^,]+', 1, 1) from dual union all 
select regexp_substr('1,2,3,4,5','[^,]+', 1, 2) from dual union all 
select regexp_substr('1,2,3,4,5','[^,]+', 1, 3) from dual union all 
select regexp_substr('1,2,3,4,5','[^,]+', 1, 4) from dual union all 
select regexp_substr('1,2,3,4,5','[^,]+', 1, 5) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Wernfried's answer is excellent, but you should know there is a big risk with the regex of the format `'[^,]+'` which one sees often as an example of how to parse delimited strings.

This only works when all elements of the list are present.  For an eye-opener, try it with the 2nd element as NULL:

```
select regexp_substr('1,,3,4,5', '[^,]+', 1, 3) from dual;

REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,,3,4,5','[^,]+',1,3)
-------------------------------------
4   

1 row selected.
```

WHAT?  `'4'` is most definitely **NOT** the 3rd element of that list! As you can see the NULL is not handled.

Please use this format of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` which does handle NULL list elements:

```
select regexp_substr('1,,3,4,5','(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) from dual;


REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,,3,4,5','(.*?)(,|$)',1,3,NULL,1)
-------------------------------------------------
3              

1 row selected.
```

The regex defines defines 2 groups, an optional set of any characters followed by a comma or the end of the line.  The arguments to REGEXP_SUBSTR
say to return the 1st group of the 3rd instance of this match.

Comment: Depending on my requirements I use either `SELECT TRIM(RTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,,3,4,5'||',', '.*?'||',', 1, LEVEL), ',')) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT('1,,3,4,5', ',')+1;` or `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,,3,4,5', '[^'||','||']+', 1, LEVEL) FROM dual CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,,3,4,5', '[^'||','||']+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;`